# Categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data

i have a panel data set.
 my dependent variable is total costs.
and almost all of my independent variables are Categorical variables. like age is "old","new"
now i have some questions.

1-should i use a dummy for all of them?(for example, only type variable has 33 values itself)
( or i can use clustering and reduce them?or any other way if you know)

2-is there a difference between behaving Categorical which they have a rank and the ones they don't have?

for example 'type' is "A","B",..."S" so no rank between A and B
but quality is "A1","A2","A3"
which A1 means highest quality

i dont know why i can find enough information about variable selections and  making data ready.
so now i have lots of variable and i think i should choose between them and also reduse number of dummies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to address this issue is by plotting the target as some box-plot for each category. Then replace each category with the median of its box-plot.

The second way is by sorting categories by the median of their boxplot and assigning numbers grom 1 to the number of categories you have.